# iterating through gzip file throws error at the end - python

Tags: python, json, gzip, boto

In Python, I open a new file, download a `.log.gz` file into this new file, gzip.open this file, and iterate through it with a for loop. Code for this shown below:

```
g = open(key.name, 'wb')
key.get_contents_to_file(g)
f = gzip.open(key.name, 'r')
for line in f:
```

For each line, I can `json.loads()` it, print that out, append it to a list, later use that list and the dictionaries in it, everything is good. But at the end of the iteration, it always throws this error:

```
IOError: CRC check failed 0x3757c5d7 != 0xc937bf89L
```

I am not sure why or how to fix it, given that the iteration works 100% as expected up until this point. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are also creating the gzipped file in the same script, you might want to check out [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-August/627751.html)

Comment: Can you gunzip the file on disk okay? if you use python to simply unzip the file, is it the same as the file you unzipped w gzip? You've got this "get_contexts_to_file" method that we have no idea what it does... does it close the file? Try `g.close()` before you open it again.

Comment: Oh sorry. That method is from boto.key. boto is the Python package for Amazon s3 stuff. The `.log.gz` file is from s3.